# Vue.js losing scope inside method

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have a component which requests data when it is created. However when the data is returned I cannot access this or any anything in the immediate parents scope.

```
// Service
class DataService {
  getDataFromService() {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve({ message: 'hello world' });
    });
    return p;
  }
}
var dataService = new DataService();

// Component
Vue.component('review', {
  created: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var that = this;
      var hello = 'world';

      // normal function
      dataService.getDataFromService().then(function(data) {
        this.foo = data.message; // 'this' is undefined
        that.bar = data.message; // 'that' is undefined
        console.log(hello);      // 'hello' is undefined
      });

      // fat arrow
      dataService.getDataFromService().then((data) => {
        this.foo = data.message; // 'this' is undefined
        that.bar = data.message; // 'that' is undefined
        console.log(hello);      // 'hello' is undefined
      });
    },
  },
});
```

In the example above both 'this' and 'that' are undefined and I'm not sure why. I am using babel & browserify to compile the code.

I've tried changing the service to use callbacks instead of promises which did not change anything. I also tried using a normal "function(data)" instead of the fat arrow function.

**Update:**
The example works in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MGadd/cdphk4hb/)! I'm guessing this means it has something to do with babel/browserify/modules.

Comment: You might have an easier time if you don't use function literals, since you've got access to ES6 syntax.

Comment: I have tried both standard and fat arrow functions. Neither made a difference. I've updated the question to include this information.

Comment: That `this` had a different value than `that` in the non-arrow function might be understandable, but `hello` being undefined means that there is a severe bug in your environment. This behaviour is not allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: The code snippet you've provided cannot exactly replicate the output that you list in the comments. The variable `hello` simply cannot log `undefined` since it's in scope and hasn't been aliased by any other local variable. The fiddle that you've provided works because it is correct (assuming that the vue library correctly binds `fetchData` with `this`). I am guessing there are two things that you're failing to understand. The case of `this` in functions and difference between arrows and function expressions.

Comment: I am fully aware how the scope should be working. Yes, it should not be logging undefined, but it is. This is why I posted the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up changing over to webpack which stopped the problem from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

using arrow function eliminates block scoping,with callback functions you must use self = this for using this,but not in arrow functions run this script and see whats going :

```
                var cb= function(f){
                    f();
                } 


                var fetchData = function() {
                    var that = this;
                    this.data ='data';

                     cb( () => {
                         console.log('---')
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(that);
                    });
                }
```